# React project running locally but not with K8s

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, npm

I'm developing a React Project. When I run it locally with:

```
 - npm install
 - npm start
```

it works. However, when I deploy it into my server with K3s the screen in browser gets black and then the log of the pod that contains the app shows this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/pages/Prices.js 1:40-93
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

The error repeats from many other .js files. For example:

```
ERROR in ./src/img/svg/SecurityIcon.js 1:40-93
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

The Dockerfile is like this: (some lines are comments to indicate that I've also tried them without solving the issue)

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
#COPY package-lock.json ./

ENV REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=dev 
ENV SERVER_ENVIRONMENT=dev 

RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./

#RUN ln -s /app/node_modules/react-refresh /app/src/react-refresh
#RUN cp /app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js /app/src/

EXPOSE 3000

#CMD ["npm", "start", "--reset-cache"]

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Anybody can give me a hand solving it?

Comment: What _is_ `npm start`? If this is a CRA app, for example, you should build then statically serve the outputs, not run the dev server in a container.

Comment: What do the actual import statements in question look like?  Does adding back the `package-lock.json` file help at all (so you're definitely using the same version of create-react-app on both systems)?

Comment: including the package-lock.json made the trick in the end. I also used this command with skaffold but not sure if the flag of the cache was also required: skaffold build  --cache-artifacts=false -p dev && skaffold render -p dev --output=xxx-infra/k8s-render/dev/all-resources-dev.yam